# Как сделать класс (или структуру) в который можно было бы записать значение просто цифрой?

Tags: c#, классы, struct, оператор-присваивания

Когда мы пишем
int a = 5;
Мы присваиваем a значение 5, но если я хочу сделать класс в который можно было бы ввести очень большое число написав именно
myclass a = 12345678987654321234567898765432123456789;
Нужно что бы класс или структура мог понимать присвоение этого набора символов(цифр), является ли это особенностью компилятора если так делать нельзя?

Comment: [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: В моём случае я хочу записать число большее чем любой формат который есть, а implicit преобразовывает один формат в другой.

Comment: Именно в таком виде это невозможно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а можете рассказать если знаете почему это работает для системных структур, а для пользовательских нельзя? Особенность компилятора?

Comment: Исправьте ваш вопрос так, что бы можно было явно понять что вы хотите не оператор неявного преобразования, или оператор присваивания, а то что вы хотите получить класс с поддержкой чисел, которые не поддерживаются в Framework'e. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Это ограничение компилятора/языка/парсера. Вероятно, можно сделать расширение с использованием Roslyn API, которое позволит обойти это (по сути, внести изменение в компилятор).

Comment: В таком виде Вы не запишите. Ибо максимальным допустимым числовым значением является `ulong MaxValue`. Внести же изменения в язык Вы просто так не сможете. Как видите, BigInteger тоже не поддерживает записи подобного вида, хотя он ничем не ограничен. А все по той причине, что когда Вы пишите числовое значение, Вы кладёте его на стэк. А значение на стэке имеет весьма определенный тип. Типа для таких больших значений не существует. Так что и использовать их нельзя. Используйте неявное приведение и строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох, придётся дать свой ответ.

Перефразированный вопрос: как записать большое число вида 12345678987654321234567898765432123456789 литералом?

Ответ: **это невозможно**. Причина - ограничение компилятора.

Применяя неявное приведение типа `implicit`, максимум можно использовать `ulong.Max`.
Применяя `BigInteger` и ему подобные классы, придётся записывать такие большие числа в виде **строки** (*строковый*, а не *числовой* литерал).

Не исключено, что можно написать расширение на Roslyn API, которое позволит использовать такие большие значения. По сути, внести изменения в компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать операторы.
Например так:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int A { get; }

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public MyClass(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(int a) => new MyClass(a);
}
```

И, соответственно, теперь можно использовать конструкцию создания экземпляра так:

```
MyClass my = 5;
Console.WriteLine(my.A); //5
```

Comment: Аналогичный ответ уже был (автор его удалил). Это не является ответом на вопрос, потому что не позволяет использовать _большие_ литералы чисел - больше, чем ulong.MaxValue и т. п.

Comment: Так в чем проблема использовать вместо int a - BigInteger?

Comment: Хороший ответ. Я его немного дополнил своим ответом.

Answer (score 0):

- Тебе это вообще не нужно. Двадцать раз подумай перед тем как это делать. Скорее всего ты просто усложняешь себе жизнь.
- Существует BigInteger, который поддерживает очень большие числа. Если BigInteger имеет в себе больше 50 чисел, то только 50 будет возвращено методом `.ToString();` Если же нужно что бы было возвращено больше символов, нужно применить "R" format. То есть: `SomeBigInteger.ToString("R");` возвратит без проблем полное значение, даже если там больше 50 символов в цифре.
- Но представим себе ситуацию, что тебе это и вправду нужно. Только нужно иметь не BigInt, а ***BigFloat***. Я бы сделал свой класс в котором бы хранилось 2 BigInt. А вся работа внутренняя была бы через строки(ну присвоение и возвращение теперешнего значения).

При присвоении значения - строка сплитилась бы на 2 части и каждая из частей бы присваивалась бы в свой собственный BigInt как целое и десятичное. Написать это нужно по тому принципу, как расписал **LiptonDev** в своем ответе.

Потом я реализовал бы собственные перезагруженные методы + - / *

Вот пример перегруженного метода умножения:

```
public static BigFloat operator *( BigFloat a, BigFloat b )
{
    //реализация
}
```

внутри была бы реализация с учетом того, что наше число поделено на дробную и целую часть внутри твоего класса BigFloat.

Но повторюсь, тебе делать так не нужно. А если ты думаешь что нужно -- ты ошибаешся 100%.

Comment: Моя цель была понять как это работает, мне это было нужно для саморазвития. Про biginteger я знаю.